# Inline aarch64 assembly UMOV source syntax

Tags: assembly, arm, 64-bit

Below is my attempt at implementing a fast popcount for AArch64 using NEON:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int count_bits(unsigned long long val) {
  unsigned long long p = 0;
  int c = 0;
  __asm__("DUP  %0.2d, %2        \n\t"
          "CNT  %0.8b, %0.8b     \n\t"
          "ADDP d0, %0.2d        \n\t"
          "UMOV %1, d0           \n\t"
          : "+w"(p), "+r"(c)
          : "r"(val) : "d0");
  return c;
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
  printf("Test: %i\n", count_bits(-1ull));
  return 0;
}
```

And the error:

```
$ gcc test.c -o test
Error: operand 2 should be a SIMD vector element -- `umov x0,d0'
```

I'm also not very sure about the `ADDP` instruction, the specifier suggests that it adds 2 dwords, but the result of `CNT` instruction is stored as 8 bytes (`%0.8b` in `ADDP` doesn't work). Shouldn't I rather use `UADALP` for summing the components ?

Comment: Well, it's quite right that you can't move a whole vector into a general-purpose register - it won't fit. The [correct syntax](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0801c/pge1427897538628.html) requires specifying which _part_ of the vector you want.

Comment: @Notlikethat Except that D0 isn't a whole vector, it's lower 64-bit scalar part of the vector register and so would fit.

Comment: @Ross bah, you're right, silly confusing vector names. Either way, an FP register specifier still isn't the correct thing for a SIMD scalar instruction.

Comment: @Notlikethat My assumption was that `d0` == `v0[0]` [as suggested by this scheme](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0801c/pge1424433185653.html).

Comment: @arul Not an entirely unreasonable assumption, but unfortunately the assembly language just wasn't defined that way. It can be quite confusing the way FP and SIMD instructions are different in many respects yet still overlap quite a lot (e.g. I think `fmov x0, d0` _would_ do exactly what you expect here).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Error: operand 2 should be a SIMD vector element -- `umov x0,d0'
```

("SIMD vector element" definition is at C1.2.4 in ARM ARM for ARMv8-A.)

```
UMOV <Wd>, <Vn>.<Ts>[<index>]
```

or for 64 bit

```
UMOV <Xd>, <Vn>.<Ts>[<index>]
```

which in your case I guess can be

```
UMOV %1, v0.D[0]
```

however I'm not sure if code is any correct now. I don't have the env. to test.

Comment: Thanks, that worked! I guess I'll have another question regarding `UADALP` soon :)